# difference between global variable and reactive value

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know what is the difference between reactiveValue and a global variable.

I can't find a correct answer :/ and i have got a problem in my following script :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  global <- list()
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choixDim", choices = param[name == input$choixCube, dim][[1]])
    updateSelectInput(session, "choixMes", choices = param[name == input$choixCube, mes][[1]])
  })

  output$ajoutColonneUi <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      if(input$ajoutColonne != "Aucun"){
        textInput("nomCol", "Nom de la colonne créée")
      },
      switch(input$ajoutColonne,
             "Ratio de deux colonnes" = tagList(
               selectInput("col1", label = "Colonne 1", choices = input$choixMes),
               selectInput("col2", label = "Colonne 2", choices = input$choixMes)
             ),
             "Indice base 100" = selectInput("col", label = "Colonne", choices = input$choixMes),
             "Evolution" = selectInput("col", label = "Colonne", choices = input$choixMes)
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$chargerCube,{
    debutChargement()
    global <- creerCube(input)
    global <- ajouterColonne(global, input)
    finChargement()

    if(!is.null(global)){
      cat('Cube chargé avec succés ! \n')
      output$handlerExport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){
          paste0("cube_generated_with_shiny_app",Sys.Date(),".csv")
        },
        content = function(file){
          fwrite(global$cube, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
      )
      output$boutons <- renderUI({
        tagList(
          downloadButton("handlerExport", label = "Exporter le cube"),
          actionButton("butValider", "Rafraichir la table/le graphique")
        )
      })
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$butValider,{
    output$pivotTable <- renderRpivotTable({
      cat('test')
      rpivotTable(data = global$cube, aggregatorName = "Sum", vals = global$mes[1], cols = global$temp)
    })
  })

})
```

global isn't updated when i want to display a rpivotTable from these data ...

Comment: Reactive variables are useful but If you only need to update the value of a global variable use the `<<-` operator instead of `<-` inside reactive expressions or subfunctions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reactiveValue is something that you can update from observers or observeEvents. Any reactive expression that is dependent on that value, will then get invalidated, and thus updated if necessary.

A global variable is a variable that is defined globally, i.e. all users that are in the process of your shiny App share that variable. The most simple example of this would be a large dataset.

**Note that your 'global' variable is not global.** You define it  as:

```
global <- list()
```

within the server. Therefore, it is unique to one user in your app, it is not shared. i.e. if it would be

```
global <- runif(1)
```

the numbers in 'global' would be different for multiple users. If you want the value to be the same, you should initialize it above your server definition. Note also that this line:

```
global <- creerCube(input)
```

does not modify your 'global' variable, because it is out of scope. It creates a variable 'global' within your observer, and discards it when the function finishes. What is probably best is to set global as a reactiveValue:

```
global <- reactiveVal()
```

and then update it as:

```
 global(creerCube(input))
```

I hope this helps.